# only show two weeks Ajax Calender

Tags: ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am using .Net3.5. I have a scenario where user selects the textbox the Ajax calender pops up. In that calender i just want to display only next two weeks. not entire month or year. How to do that?

```
<tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            Next Update Date
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td align="left">
                                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditUpdateDt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                                            <cc2:CalendarExtender CssClass="AjaxCalendar" OnClientShowing="DisplayDateToday"
                                                                ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" PopupButtonID="txtEditUpdateDt" PopupPosition="BottomLeft"
                                                                TargetControlID="txtEditUpdateDt" Enabled="True" />
                                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valtxtEditUpdateDt" runat="server" Display="None"
                                                                ControlToValidate="txtEditUpdateDt" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Date." ValidationExpression="((^(10|12|0?[13578])([/])(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(11|0?[469])([/])(30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(2[0-8]|1[0-9]|0?[1-9])([/])((1[8-9]\d{2})|([2-9]\d{3}))$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2468][048]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([3579][26]00)$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][0][48])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][2468][048])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([1][89][13579][26])$)|(^(0?2)([/])(29)([/])([2-9][0-9][13579][26])$))"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                                            <cc2:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender3" runat="server" Enabled="True"
                                                                TargetControlID="valtxtEditUpdateDt">
                                                            </cc2:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Dario said, I don't think you can't limit it in the simple ajax control. An alternative option would be to add a range validator.

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="RangeValidatorDT"
                    runat="server"
                    ControlToValidate="txtEditUpdateDt"
                    ErrorMessage="* Invalid date range"
                    Type="Date">
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

Then on the page load

```
RangeValidatorDT.MinimumValue = System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()
RangeValidatorDT.MaximumValue = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(15).ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what I know you can't do it, this calendar extender is very easy to use, but very limited, if you use the Calendar control you would be able to enable only the days that you want.